# Getting segmentation fault while malloc'ing

Tags: c

I get a segmentation fault the second time malloc runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int keywords_init(char *str, char ***str_arr);

int main(void) {

    char str[] = "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3";
    char **str_arr = NULL;
    int arr_elements;

    arr_elements = keywords_init(str, &str_arr);

    return 0;
}

int keywords_init(char *str, char ***str_arr) {
    int i;
    char *pch;

    /* String break */
    pch = strtok(str, ",");
    for (i = 0; pch != NULL; i++) {
        *str_arr = realloc (*str_arr, (i+1)*sizeof(char *));
        *str_arr[i] = malloc (strlen(pch) + 1);
        strcpy(*str_arr[i], pch);
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }

    return i;   
}
```

What confuses me is that if I don't pass the address of str_arr to keywords_init and use a double pointer instead of a triple one in keywords_init it works just fine.

Comment: i think the use of the triple pointer indicates a slight design flaw

Comment: You can avoid the three-star programming by returning an array of pointers and passing the count by pointer. Future maintainers will actually love you. And...  *hint*:  avoid strtok() it is evil and it sucks.

Comment: Currently he is returning two things: the "double pointer", and the int. You seem to be suggesting returning `char **` and having parameter `int *`, as opposed to returning `int` and parameter `char ***`. I don't see why the latter should be avoided on principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting bitten by operator precedence/associativity - change both occurrences of:

```
*str_arr[i]
```

to:

```
(*str_arr)[i]
```